# How to add event listener in JS if html5 video fails to load

Tags: javascript, django

In a Django website I've built, users can add videos for others to see and comment on. Not all users have devices that support video playback, and thus for such edge cases, I want to allow **video download**.

To do this, I first need to detect whether the video failed or not. How can I do that? I have a working solution below, but with issues I need to resolve.

---

Currently I'm trying the following in my Django template (where all videos are listed using a `ListView`). This actually works, but *breaks down if I reload the page*:

```
<script>
    var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');
    for (var i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
        (function() {
            var v = videos[i];
            var s = v.querySelector('source');
                //console.log(source);
            s.addEventListener('error', function(ev) {
                var d = document.createElement('div');
                d.innerHTML = v.innerHTML;
                console.log("hello")
                console.log(v);
                v.parentNode.replaceChild(d, v);
            }, false);
        }());
    }
</script>
```

I.e. first I go through all `video` tags in the HTML page, then for each tag, I look up the `source` tag inside. Next, I try to add an event listener to the source tag, catch the error, and do some processing. However, I've found that the event listener is not fired if I reload the page. Maybe the event handler is being added too late; i.e. the browser already attempted to access the video source before the event handler was added. Can someone help me out here? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try putting the `error` event handler on the video element and not on the source element. Also are using something that will actually cause an error like an invalid url or a video that has a format that you know the browser doesn't support?

Comment: Ahh, seems the html5 specification moved the error handling to the source element instead of the media element. Since it seems to not work on reload, the only thing I can think of is that maybe the event handler is being added too late. ie browser already attempted to access video source before event handler was added. And the only thing I can think of that would help if that is in fact the case would be to add an inline event handler. `<source onerror="errorHandler(error)">`

Comment: @PatrickEvans: makes sense. I'm actually a back-end developer and fairly new to JS. So what you mean is I should enclose the JS code inside a function called `errorHandler` and call it inline in the source tag, correct? Would be good if you included that as an illustrative answer.

Comment: Yea that is what I mean, I didn't enter it as an answer as I do not know if it would actually solve your problem. As for illustrating it, you would want the rendered page to end up something like this: http://pastebin.com/1KMfPBiJ

Comment: @PatrickEvans: seems the only supported tags for `onerror` are <img>, <input type="image">, <object>, <script> and <style> (http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onerror.asp).

Comment: It's there, `<source>` ([HTMLSourceElement](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSourceElement)) inheirts [HTMLElement](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement) which inheirts [GlobalEventHandlers](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers) which `onerror` is part of. Also since you can do `addEventListener("error"...)` you can add the same with the element propetry `element.onerror = ...` or as a html attribute. JSFiddle demo of it working: https://jsfiddle.net/pevj1v4z/. Note w3schools isn't always up to date in their documentation

Comment: I suspect your error event might be firing before your script tag is running. You might try adding the event listener to body in a script tag before the video tag, and using the capture phase for event delegation. There might also be some other ways to check if the video errored after the fact, I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `load` event of `window` to set `src` of `<video>` element, [`Node.replaceChild()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/replaceChild), `download` attribute at `<a>` element

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var video = document.querySelector("video");
  video.addEventListener("error", function(event) {
    var a = document.createElement("a");
    a.href = this.src;
    a.innerHTML = "download media";
    a.download = ""; // set suggested file name here
    this.parentElement.replaceChild(a, this);
  });
  video.src = "media.file";
}
```

```html
<video controls="">
  <source src="" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: I used `querySelectorAll('video')` instead of `querySelector('video')` because all my videos are listed via a for loop, and this JS code sits *after the for loop*. So I'm thinking the above won't work for my particular set up?

Comment: @HassanBaig stacksnippets is example of approach. You should be able to substitute `.querySelectorAll()`, `for` loop for `.querySelector()` single event listener. Use `load` event of `window`, set `src` of element after attaching `error` event listener to element

Comment: Yep, that's what I thought. I'm going to try it out and let you know how it goes. Thanks for helping out, I'm just beginning with JS, and it's hard to get my head around all the examples and resources I need to research to put the jigsaw puzzle together :-)